# How to make an event listener respond to unique buttons when they dynamically appear from being added elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble getting a single function to control a dropdown menu on buttons. When the first button is clicked, the dropdown appears, however when a second button is added, and that button is clicked, the dropdown menu corresponds to the first button.

I'm adding buttons dynamically when a user clicks "Buy" so I can't make multiple functions or variables that would correspond to each buttons.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing first, it's a bad practice of having multiple elements with same `id` . Id should be unique.
```document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
```
this piece of code will always trigger the first element with that ID. You could target all elements by referring with classname.

Comment: I changed the line you pointed out to:       document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown").classList.toggle("show"); and added a class="dropdown" to the same div element as id="myDropdown". Now none of the dropdowns will appear when I click either of them.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of element. Not one single element.

Comment: @Chay22 I replaced getElementById with getElementsByClassName('dropdown') and added that class to the div with id="myDiv" but now no dropdown will appear for either of them. Am I implementing it correctly???

Comment: you cannot have two identical id...

Comment: @Wils, assuming I have taken out the ID's and implemented getElementsByClassName('dropdown') and inserted the dropdown class in the div where the id "myDIV" used to be, would that work.

Comment: @TylerMorales see my answer, and I suggest you move on to jQuery for easier life.

Answer (score 1):

this is to find the sibling class and toggle it, so you can reuse your function.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(element) {

for (var i = 0; i < element.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
classname=element.parentNode.childNodes[i].className;
  if (!classname) continue;
    if (classname.includes("dropdown-content")) {
  element.parentNode.childNodes[i].classList.toggle("show");
      break;
    }        
}
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">menu 1</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">menu 2</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this works, however, once the button is clicked it does not toggle to display none.

Comment: answer updated.yes, because the classname changed, so == no longer true, here I used includes to check if the class match.

Comment: thanks, @wils, this will work for now, and i'll just tweak it to the way I like it. I checked out bootstrap dropdowns and when a new button was dynamically added, the dropdowns worked with no issue. However, I don't want to trust a black box and want to understand the code.

Comment: bootstrap is way easier. if you find my answer useful, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```js
//This function will be called on every click to hide previously 
//opened dropdowns if any
const hideAll = () => {
  const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(dropDowns, (item)=> {
     if(item.classList.contains('show')){
        item.classList.remove('show');
      } 
  });
};

//showDropDown 'myFunction' accepts parameter 'id' to select unique element, 
//inside this method the hideAll function will be called to close any other 
//opened dropdowns and opens a required dropdown
const showDropDown = id => {
  hideAll();
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show"); 
};

//reset function is to close all dropdowns if the click is triggered outside button
const reset = (e) => {
  if(!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
    hideAll();
  }
};

//adding click event listener to window to reset opened dropdowns 
window.addEventListener('click', reset);

//selecting buttons and assigning to variable btns
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn');

//calling Array's forEach method, passing to it btns
//inside the loop adding a click event listener to each button 
//on click the showDropDown will be called with dynamically generated id
 
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, (btn, index) => {
   btn.addEventListener('click', () => showDropDown(`drop_${index + 1}`))
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .show {display: block;}
```

```html
<!-- removed onclick attributes and added unique ids to dropdown-content -->

<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="drop_1" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="drop_2" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might want to add a few lines on what you fixed and where. This way someone else with little knowledge will be able to learn faster from your solution. End of Review.

Comment: Yes, this does work, however when a new button is added dynamically through some other function, I have no control over what the ID would be so this option would not be sufficient for additional buttons that are added without me explicitly creating them

Comment: @TylerMorales can you share the code how the element is generated dynamically?

Comment: I am using handlebars @IrecoGnizedYou .This is the originator: when the buy button is pressed a new item is added to a cart view`<div class='items-container'>

    {{# each products}}
    <div class='item-container'>
       
        {{!-- buttons --}}
        <div class='purchase-container'>
          
            <a class='button buy' href="/add-to-cart/{{ this._id }}">
                <h3>Buy</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}`

Comment: This is the view of the cart and when the buy button is pressed from above, a new product is generated with the same format`{{#each products}}

    <div class='product-container'>
     
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn button">Action</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <div id="axnBtn" class="user-action">Reduce 1</div>
                <div id="axnBtn" class="user-action">Remove All</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{/each}}`

Comment: @TylerMorales Is it a handlebars? if so you could add id inside the each loop  id="drop-{{@index + 1}}"

Comment: @IrecoGnizedYou, yes, I am using handlebars. That's what I did that originally and the dropdown would only appear for the first button.

Comment: {{#each products}} <div class='product-container'> <div class="dropdown"> <div  id="drop_{{@index + 1}}" class="dropbtn button">Action</div> <div class="dropdown-content"> <div id="axnBtn" class="user-action">Reduce 1</div> <div id="axnBtn" class="user-action">Remove All</div> </div> </div> </div> {{/each}}